# How to add an extra page inside existing file in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I am now working on with the webview process, i have successfully coded to save the webview contents in my app. But, now while saving my webview content, i need to add a extra page to the existing view inside the webview. I searched quite through several links, stil i can't get an idea.

Below is my code:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(
        this);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "Textview");
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Sorry but i see no saving of content. Nor do i see views.

Comment: I can't get you, well no problem i found a way to add an extra page anyway thanks